# Polar Area chart JS

Tags: javascript, animation, chart.js

I have a polarArea chart on my dashboard. I want to add an animation to it. Could you please let me know how to do it? If you provide me with one, I would be really happy.

```
// three provinces chart
let threeProvinces = ['Kabul', 'Herat', 'Mazar'];
let provincesCrimes = [131, 95, 50];
const crimeChartThreeProvinces = document.getElementById('crimeChartThreeProvinces');

new Chart(crimeChartThreeProvinces, {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
    labels: threeProvinces,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Traffic Crimes',
      data: provincesCrimes,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,0.9)',
        'rgba(54,162,235,0.9)',
        'rgba(255,206,86,0.9)',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    // new 

    // end new 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited and working snippet with animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PolarArea Chart with Animation</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="crimeChartThreeProvinces" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

    <script>
        let threeProvinces = ['Kabul', 'Herat', 'Mazar'];
    let provincesCrimes = [131, 95, 50];
    const crimeChartThreeProvinces = document.getElementById('crimeChartThreeProvinces');

    new Chart(crimeChartThreeProvinces, {
            type: 'polarArea',
            data: {
                labels: threeProvinces,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Traffic Crimes',
                    data: provincesCrimes,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,0.9)',
                        'rgba(54,162,235,0.9)',
                        'rgba(255,206,86,0.9)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                animation: {
                    animateRotate: true,
                    animateScale: true
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

you have to pass this in your chart options

```
maintainAspectRatio: false,
            animation: {
                animateRotate: true,
                animateScale: true
            }
```